# Spring RestTemplate checking response status before casting to response object leads to no suitable converter error

Tags: java, spring, rest, jaxb, resttemplate

I am using the following line to obtain a response object using Spring RestTemplate:

```
 final ResponseEntity<Object> genericErrorResponse = restTemplate
            .postForEntity("urlvalue.com", request,
                       Object.class);
```

My goal is to check

```
if the response is 200: cast to Custom200ResponseModel

If response is 500: cast to CustomErrorModel
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
 org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: 
 no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/xml]
```

All my models have `@XmlRootElement` on them - and i can cast directly using

```
response.postForObject(...)
```

So what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Custom200ResponseModel.class in the postForEntity method:

```
final ResponseEntity<Custom200ResponseModel> genericErrorResponse = restTemplate
        .postForEntity("urlvalue.com", request,
                   Custom200ResponseModel.class);
```

This will work for your 200 response. Then you can wrap the call in a try catch and handle the RestClientResponseException based on the reponse code. If the response code in the exception is a 500 you can manually create and populate a CustomErrorModel object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the response as a String, and then use Jackson ObjectMapper to convert to whatever class you want.